how do I add cookies to 2captcha?
Can anyone please give me a working example of adding cookies to the worker's browser in 2captcha? Please do not link a page as I have researched the entire internet but no valid working example. Not even on 2captcha's page.
It is possible according to here but it doesn't work.
